# How to solve the problem about 'filter' field must be of BSON type object

Tags: regex, mongodb, go, find, bson

I want to solve this problem when called find query.

This is running Golang, and use package ""gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson".

```
import "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
import "fmt"

    /* mongodb */
    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{1.1.1.1+ ":" + 27017},
        Database: MgName,
        Username: MgId,
        Password: MgPasswd,
    }

    mgconn, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[ERR ] mongodb : %s\n", err)
        return (-1)
    }

    /* error check on every access */
    mgconn.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})

    MgConn := mgconn.DB(MgName)

    col := MgConn.C("test")
    ip := "1.1.1.1"
    docs := []interface{}{
        bson.M{"message": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{`name:agent`, ""}}},
        bson.M{"message": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{ip, ""}}},
    }

    err := col.Find(docs).Sort("-time").One(&statistic)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[INFO] mongodb select : %s\n", err)
    }
```

This is the error message:

```
Failed to parse: filter: [ { message: { $regex: /name:agent/ } }, { 
message: { $regex: /192.168.18.61/ } } ]. 'filter' field must be of 
BSON type object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb requires a query object but you're sending an array. I suppose you wanted to do a logical-OR of the two conditions, so try this:

```
docs := bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
    {"message": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{`name:agent`, ""}}},
    {"message": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{ip, ""}}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for asking my question.
I want to send $and query, so could you ask me $and query??

Comment: Replace $or with $and.